# P2P networks mechanism

Tags: networking, network-programming, p2p

Im looking for some technical information about P2P networks.
It seems there isnt enough info about this subject on the internet.

I read about some popular p2p networks on wikipedia as Napster, Kademlia , etc but Its poor and too complex for 'beginners',

To be more specific - I do understand how naspter style p2p networks work - when there's a main server which keeps the necessary info and direct each client to the right peers,
but things are getting complicated with Kademlia p2p network style, when 
(correct me if Im wrong) the peers are connected to each other, Its a big mess and I dont understand how exactly It works.

Im sorry for my english, Im not a native english speaker:).

thanks

Comment: Which part don't you understand, say in the Kadmelia article? Do you understand what a DHT is? What about a hash table?

Comment: I have [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910804/what-is-the-state-of-art-on-implementing-a-p2p-message-broadcast-network/45385971#45385971) with pointers to design docs of the [Dat Project](https://datproject.org), which is a nice case study.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a general survey of P2P networks, then this paper might give you a nice overview:
[A Survey and Comparison of Peer-to-Peer Overlay Network Schemes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.109.6124).

If you are just interested in understanding Kademlia, I highly recommend that you first understand wat Distributed Hash Tables (DHTs) are. The most simple example of a DHT is Chord and is described in [this paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/chord/papers/paper-ton.pdf).